# Image is not displaying on google map using LeafletJS

Tags: javascript, leaflet

After setting map bounds and image url using  Leaflet js, the image only displays the extent on google map, the real image is not shown how can I solve this.

Comment: Insufficient information. Please provide more details (like your attempt, code).

Comment: Do you use leaflet with angularjs by leaflet-ui?

Comment: I do not use leaflet but here is my code  /*****************ADDING IMAGES TO THE MAP*******************
 var imageUrl='/Images/CKP2.png';
 //  Image bounds describe the topleft and bottom right coordinates 
 var imageBounds=[
 [-22.0,22.5],
 [-26.18,25.452]
 ]
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl,imageBounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(imageBounds);

Comment: @charx Welcome to SO. Please use the "edit" grey link below your question to include your code. Also make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)